# tidyr extract groups where not all groups are always present

Tags: r, regex, tidyr

This is very similar, if not duplicate to [Use tidyr's function `extract` with optional capture group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73927505/use-tidyrs-function-extract-with-optional-capture-group) and [Tidyr separate with optional groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67807641/tidyr-separate-with-optional-groups). However, I don't manage to get the suggested optional capture  working and I feel it might be due to the two separate groups that I am trying to optionally capture.

```r
library(tidyverse)
foo <- data.frame(test = c("a big tomato b big orange", "b big tomato", "b big apple a big pear"))

extract(foo, test, into = c("group_1", "fruit_1", "group_2", "fruit_2"), 
        regex = "([a|b]) big ([a-zA-Z]*) ([a|b]) big ([a-zA-Z]*)")
#>   group_1 fruit_1 group_2 fruit_2
#> 1       a  tomato       b  orange
#> 2    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
#> 3       b   apple       a    pear

## same result, with attempt to use the optional capture group
extract(foo, test, into = c("group_1", "fruit_1", "group_2", "fruit_2"), 
        regex = "([a|b]) big ([a-zA-Z]*) (?:([a|b]) big ([a-zA-Z]*))?")
## same result
extract(foo, test, into = c("group_1", "fruit_1", "group_2", "fruit_2"), 
        regex = "([a|b]) big ([a-zA-Z]*) (?:([a|b]))? big (?:([a-zA-Z]*))?")

## desired result
foo %>% 
  separate(test, into = c("group_1", "big1", "fruit_1", "group_2", "big2", "fruit_2"), sep = " ") %>%
  select(-starts_with("big"))
#> Warning: Expected 6 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 1 rows [2].
#>   group_1 fruit_1 group_2 fruit_2
#> 1       a  tomato       b  orange
#> 2       b  tomato    <NA>    <NA>
#> 3       b   apple       a    pear
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the space before the optional pattern should also be made optional. Move it to the group:

```r
regex = "[ab] big ([a-zA-Z]*)(?: [ab] big ([a-zA-Z]*))?"
##                           ^^^^
```

Note the `(?:[a|b])`  pattern is better written as `[ab]`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good opportunity to showcase the new `tidyr::separate_wider_regex`. In this new alternative to `extract`, we have a `patterns` argument: a vector with optionaly named elements. Unnamed elements are discarded, and named elements are extracted into columns with the same name. Feels like a good alternative to complex regexes in the `pattern` argument of `extract`.

The `too_few` argument sets how to handle the output if not all patterns are matched, which enables optinal capture behaviour.

```
library(tidyr) #should be version >= 1.3.0

separate_wider_regex(data = foo, 
                     cols = test,
                     patterns = c(group_1 = "[ab]",
                                  " big ",
                                  fruit_1 = "[a-zA-Z]+",
                                  " ",
                                  group_2 = "[ab]",
                                  " big ",
                                  fruit_2 = "[a-zA-Z]+"),
                     too_few = "align_start"
                     )
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  group_1 fruit_1 group_2 fruit_2
  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
1 a       tomato  b       orange 
2 b       tomato  NA      NA     
3 b       apple   a       pear
```

Comment: Nice. Definitely didn't know this function. Thanks for pointing it out :)